# Query запрос в dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Есть такой query запрос в dynamodb

```
{ TableName: '*******************',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'customerId = :hkey',
  FilterExpression: 'objectType = :type and #status in (:s0)',
  ExpressionAttributeValues:
   { ':hkey': '*******************',
     ':type': 'validation',
     ':s0': 'pending' },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#status': 'status' } }
{ TableName: 'i*******************',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'customerId = :hkey',
  FilterExpression: 'objectType = :type',
  ExpressionAttributeValues:
   { ':hkey': '*******************',
     ':type': 'validation' } }
```

Возникла проблема с тем что запрос стал превышать 1мб, и соответственно не все items отдаются на query запрос, меня очень смущает что запрос достиг такого размера. Посоветуйте как на примере моего запроса, можно его сделать более производительней. Всем добра)

Comment: Уточните: вас интересует, откуда так много данных (ну, видимо в таблице их много стало и под фильтр попадает много) или почему не все данные отдаются? Тут скорее всего срабатывает троттлинг (смотрите настройки таблицы).

Comment: Пожалуй я не совсем правильно описал проблему и задачу,  сейчас около 1500 тысячи элементов попадает под фильтр, причем выполняется 2 query запроса, в респонсе возвращается ключ lastEvaluatedKey, по которому я могу получить недостающие элементы, но является ли нормальным решением делать дополнительные запросы, в будущем планируется делать фильтрацию на 20000 айтемов. я понимаю что 10 query запросов это не выход из ситуации, возможно есть best practice, которые решают эту проблему. Если есть опыт в таких делах, посоветуйте что-нибудь, возможно стоит пересмотреть подход фильтрации.